# creating table from a left outer join query

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, table a has two columns , email and course. table b has one column email. I am trying to get a result from table a that will exclude all the similar emails in table b.I used this

```
SELECT * FROM EnqAll
LEFT OUTER JOIN Unsubscribe
ON EnqAll.EMAIL = Unsubscribe.Email
WHERE Unsubscribe.EMAIL IS null
```

it returned the result with three columns email, course and email(this last column is null). I tried to create a table with this,but I couldn't, on further reading I was advised to first create the table in the database and insert, but I cant create a table with similar column name, please how can I go about this, I am using sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT EnqAll.*  INTO NewTable FROM EnqAll
LEFT OUTER JOIN Unsubscribe
ON EnqAll.EMAIL = Unsubscribe.Email
WHERE Unsubscribe.EMAIL IS null
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use the initial code, but I was advised not to use *, but specify the actual column, after which i created the table and inserted it  ( INSERT INTO Ncssubscribers
SELECT EnqAll.EMAIL , EnqAll.COURSE FROM EnqAll
LEFT OUTER JOIN AllCs
ON EnqAll.EMAIL = AllCs.Email
WHERE AllCs.EMAIL IS null)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EnqAll 
WHERE EnqAll.EMAIL NOT IN Unsubscribe.Email
```